# Residue of a function at essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I have the function  $\sin (1/z) $ . The point 0 is an essential singularity of this function, right? Since it is undefined at 0. Can you explain me how to find the residue of this function at 0?

Comment: Hint: in the Laurent expansion, what is the coefficient of 1/z?

Answer (score 1):

The residue of an essential singularity of a function at $z=0$ is always the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of the function.  For the function $f(z)=\sin{\left ( z^{-1} \right )} $, the Laurent expansion about $z=0$ is

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{-(2 n+1)}}{(2 n+1)!} $$

The coefficient of $z^{-1}$ here is $(-1)^0/(2 \cdot 0+1)! = 1$, which is the residue sought.

Comment: Isn't that the Taylor expansion of $sin(1/z) $ about z=0 ? Are they the same thing?

Comment: @Thomas : yes.  This works because sine is entire in the complex plane.  This the above expansion is valid outside of $z=0$.

Comment: Oh ..so if I have functions like sine or cosine or e^x I can just take the Taylor series and find the coefficient like you did ? Also sorry for expressing the end like that but I'm on phone and I don't remember how to write it properly.

Comment: @Thomas : correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know any good books about complex analysis?

Comment: @Thomas : I'm a fan of Ahlfors.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything !

Comment: @Thomas There's a $\texttt{.pdf}$ edition of [Ahlfors Book in internet](https://editorialdinosaurio.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/ahlfors_-_complex_analysis.pdf)